# How to prove the function is smooth after define it in a removable singularity

Tags: functions

Consider the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{sinz}$ on $[0,1]$. If we define it is 0 at 0 as its limit.

How to show the function after adding definition on $0$ is smooth?

It may be apparent, but could anyone tell me some short insightful reasons?

Comment: It isn't, what happens at $z=\pi$, for example.

Comment: Updated, let us say it is in [0,1]

Comment: Then this is the difference of smooth functions on that interval, and you can immediately check at $0$ that the singularity is removable.

Comment: That is my problem, could you help me connect why 0 is removable then after defining this function at this point, the function become smooth(of course originally the function is smooth except at this point)? which theory says this? thanks, I want to get the insights.

Comment: it maybe obvious for you, but could you say some details? And I know intuitively right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the function is smooth in a neighborhood of zero by noting that it is a difference of analytic functions in a punctured neighborhood and that

$$\lim_{z\to 0}z\left({1\over z}-{1\over\sin z}\right)=0$$

Therefore, with $g(z)=zf(z)$ we see that

$$\int_C f(z)=\int_{C}{g(z)\over z}=0$$

for any simple, cloesd curve around $0$. Therefore, by Morera's theorem, we have that $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, lacking some knowledge in complex analysis.

Comment: By the way is there any way to show this only in real analysis? assuming z is real?

Comment: Taylor's theorem can give you explicit estimates which guarantee analyticity in a neighborhood of zero as well, but it is much messier.